# How to create multiple objects in SpriteKit which follow the same methods?

Tags: oop, sprite-kit

I am currently creating a game and am working on creating multiple objects of the same type that each follow their classes methods separately. Eventually the goal is to have Object A be created in either the top left, or top right corner of the screen on a random interval and bounce off the left and right walls until they hit the bottom of the screen.

For testing purposes, I created a new 'Object A' each time the user touches the screen inside the touchesBegan method.

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    objectA = [HHObjectA objectA];
    [world addChild:objectA];
    objectA.position = CGPointMake(world.scene.frame.size,width/12, world.scene.frame.size.height/3.2);
    [objectA moveLeft];
}
```

Although indeed this does create a new 'Object A' each time the screen is pressed, in the location I specified; each 'Object A' is connected. If the first 'Object A' collides with the left wall, each 'Object A' will move right. If one 'Object A' gets stuck on another, the rest glitch. I thought potentially changing the name of the second 'Object A' might make each run separately, but this too had the same result as above. My next thought would be arrays, however I'm not sure how many Object A's I will be needed per level.

What would be the best way to achieve my desired goal?

Comment: You need to create a "new" object. What you're doing is just creating multiple copies of the same object. You do that by subclassing - in your case SKSpriteNode.

Comment: This is what I meant by changing the name of the object, however it had the same results.

Comment: Create a new SKSpriteNode class. Then you can instantiate it by using SKSpriteNode *myNode = [[MyClass alloc] init];

Comment: objectA = [HHObjectA objectA]; instantiates a new Object from my ObjectA class that is a SKSpriteNode class :/

Comment: I'm using objectA to be generic. Basically it's the bad guy class for my game. It's a SKSpriteNodeClass.